# MFMailComposer can send m4a file, but can't read it on the other side.

Tags: ios, audio, format, m4a

I've used MFMailComposer to send an m4a file created by AVAudioRecorder, but I can't play it back on my mac. When I download the app package through the xcode organizer, I still cannot play back the raw m4a. Does anyone have any idea how to get the m4a to play? I've tried formatting my own m4a's through core audio(using the Dirac library), but I still have the same no playing m4a problem. It seems that the AVAudioRecorder should make perfectly formatted files since it's all abstracted in there, but it seems like only AVAudioRecorder understands the format(not even itunes will read it).

Here is my mailer code:

```
MFMailComposeViewController *mailer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    mailer.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [mailer setSubject:@"Feedback"];

    NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"info@x.com", nil];
    [mailer setToRecipients:toRecipients];

    NSArray *pathComponents = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                               [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject],
                               @"sound.m4a",
                               nil];

    NSURL *urlfile = [NSURL fileURLWithPathComponents:pathComponents];
    NSError* error = nil;
    NSData* audioData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:urlfile options:0 error:&error];

    [mailer addAttachmentData:audioData mimeType:@"audio/mp4" fileName:@"sound.m4a"];

    NSString *emailBody = @" ";
    [mailer setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check following:

```
NSData* audioData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:urlfile options:0 error:&error];

if(audioData.length)
```

Then only add in the mail.

There might be issue in path url file.

Comment: I just tried that, and there is data in audioData - 97kB of it. However, I still can't figure out how to play it back on my computer. I can also download it straight from the phone(through organizer), and i have the same playback problem. Any help in playing back the file would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you please save the data with file type mp4  also change the extension to .mp4 and try playing on Mac.

Comment: I just tried saving as an MP4, but then copied it to another location. Turns out I was accessing it at the same time I was trying to write it and that was causing an error. I can now mail an MP4 that I can play back. Thanks for your help.